# Why did Jupiter spiral into the inner solar system?

Tags: jupiter, solar-system-evolution

We know over 4 billion years ago, Jupiter was created and started to head into the inner solar system until Saturn pulled Jupiter back out. In fact, we wouldn’t be here if Jupiter stayed inside the inner solar system. My question is, what force pulled Jupiter inside the inner solar system in the first place?

Comment: See [Grand tack hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_tack_hypothesis)

Comment: The linked article doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Yes, I know that Jupiter migrated inward. That’s what I said in my question. I am wondering why Jupiter migrated inward.

Comment: I wasn't intending to suggest the linked article directly addressed the question.  There's a lot of references for that article that may contain the answer or at least provide a good starting point.  From the first reference in the Wikipedia article "Because a huge amount of gas still swirled around the sun back then, the giant planet got caught in the currents of flowing gas and started to get pulled toward the sun. Jupiter spiraled slowly inward until it settled at a distance of about 1.5 astronomical units—about where Mars is now. (Mars was not there yet.)"

Comment: I'd attempt an answer myself, but I'm not feeling that great today.

Comment: You may found your answer here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44768/35206

Comment: Short answer, which other commenters omitted is "we don't know, we just have many ideas that might work". After saying that first, only then I feel is it legit to reference all the theory papers.